# can't use colon pair in `qqww` or `qqww:to` struct

Tags: raku

I want to generate a json row using a `Class`, I overwrite the `gist` method, so that it will print what I want:

```
my $ak = '7111ac873c9dcd5fc335ded47630d050';
my $st = '1523451601875';
my $ifo = 'true';
my $uu = "15778787898988090";

class Stay {
  has $.ak  is rw = '7111ac873c9dcd5fc335ded47630d050';
  has $.uu  is rw;
  has $.ifo is rw;
  has $.st  is rw;

  method gist() {
    #return qqww/{"ev":"app","ak":"$!ak","uu":"$!uu","ifo":"$!ifo","st":"$!st"}/;

    return qqww:to「EOF」;
    {"ev":"app","ak":"$!ak","uu":"$!uu","ifo":"$!ifo","st":"$!st"}
    EOF
  }
}

say Stay.new(uu => $uu, ifo => $ifo, st => $st);
```

but fails with:

```
===SORRY!=== Error while compiling /Users/ohmycloud/Desktop/stay.pl6
Confused
at /Users/ohmycloud/Desktop/stay.pl6:18
------>     {"ev":⏏"app","ak":"$!ak","uu":"$!uu","ifo":"$!i
    expecting any of:
        colon pair
```

What I want is:

```
{"ev":"app","ak":"7111ac873c9dcd5fc335ded47630d050","uu":"15778787898988090","ifo":"true","st":"1523451601875"}
```

Why I can't use colon pair in `qqww` or `qq:to` struct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [unquoting](https://docs.perl6.org/language/quoting#Unquoting):

```
method gist() {
    return '{"ev":"app","ak":"\qq[$!ak]","uu":"\qq[$!uu]","ifo":"\qq[$!ifo]","st":"\qq[$!st]"}':
}
```

which will return

```
{"ev":"app","ak":"7111ac873c9dcd5fc335ded47630d050","uu":"15778787898988090","ifo":"true","st":"1523451601875"}
```

Colons are going to get in the way if you use `qqww` or similar.

Answer (score 6):

`{}` have special meaning in double quote. They must be escaped

```perl6
qq:to「EOF」;
\{"ev":"app","ak":"$!ak","uu":"$!uu","ifo":"$!ifo","st":"$!st"\}
EOF
```

you need `qq`, not `qqww` which make list.

You can use `fmt`

```perl6
(:ev<app>, :$!ak, :$!uu, :$!ifo, :$!st).fmt('"%s":"%s"', ',').fmt('{%s}')
```

or `JSON::Fast`

```perl6
require JSON::Fast <&to-json>;
{:ev<app>, :$!ak, :$!uu, :$!ifo, :$!st}.&to-json
```

or even

```perl6
require JSON::Fast <&to-json>;
self.^attributes.map( {.name => .get_value(self)} ).Hash.&to-json
```

Comment: An alternate way is to disable the handling of `{ }` inside double quoted strings: `say qq:!c/{ foo }/` will show `{ foo }`.  I once wrote a blog post about all of the myriad ways of quoting: https://perl6advent.wordpress.com/2014/12/16/quoting-on-steroids/